# Validate email in Nativescript dataform

Tags: validation, nativescript, dataform

I have tried using a custom regex for email validation in nativescript Dataform but only one that work is this:

```
"validators": [
                { "name": "NonEmpty" },
                {
                "name": "RegEx",
                "params": {
                    "regEx": "^[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}\\@telerik.com$",
                    "errorMessage": "Please provide proper email address."
                }
              }
            ]
```

I know if seems very trivial, but my regex that typically work in a web environment does not work here. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I guess never searched hard enough. I actually found one that work:
^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$

Comment: It turns out this is not correct on all counts. it allows some emails addresses while blocking others that follow a similar pattern. I am not sure why. So I am back to where I started. Trying to find a regEx for validating an email in Nativescript dataform.